# wro4j sass preprocessor throwing exception in spring integration

Tags: java, wro4j

I am working on adding the sass support for the css, and added sassCss preprocessor to my configuration, Its not working as expected rather throwing exception

> ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.SassCssProcessor@18f6b97. Reason: Bad language version: 180

Here is the exception:

```
    SEVERE: Exception occured
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: The processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.SassCssProcessor@18f6b97 faile while processing uri: /css/framework/reset.2.css
    at ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException.wrap(WroRuntimeException.java:69)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.process(ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.java:67)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.BenchmarkProcessorDecorator.process(BenchmarkProcessorDecorator.java:44)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.DefaultProcessorDecorator.process(DefaultProcessorDecorator.java:42)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.PreProcessorExecutor$2.process(PreProcessorExecutor.java:228)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.PreProcessorExecutor.applyPreProcessors(PreProcessorExecutor.java:207)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.PreProcessorExecutor.processAndMerge(PreProcessorExecutor.java:103)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.PreProcessorExecutor.processAndMerge(PreProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor.process(GroupsProcessor.java:83)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:101)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:35)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.get(AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:55)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.serveProcessedBundle(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:63)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:159)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:339)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad language version: 180
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.checkLanguageVersion(Context.java:772)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.setLanguageVersion(Context.java:741)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.script.RhinoScriptBuilder.createContext(RhinoScriptBuilder.java:69)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.script.RhinoScriptBuilder.<init>(RhinoScriptBuilder.java:45)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.script.RhinoScriptBuilder.<init>(RhinoScriptBuilder.java:40)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.script.RhinoScriptBuilder.newChain(RhinoScriptBuilder.java:220)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.support.sass.SassCss.initScriptBuilder(SassCss.java:41)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.support.sass.SassCss.process(SassCss.java:67)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.SassCssProcessor.process(SassCssProcessor.java:64)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.LazyProcessorDecorator.process(LazyProcessorDecorator.java:49)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.SupportAwareProcessorDecorator.process(SupportAwareProcessorDecorator.java:39)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.process(ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.java:56)
    ... 35 more
```

wro4j version: 1.8.0